# Taking screenshot of a specific space using python

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to take a screenshot of a specific region using python.

I wrote this code:

```
import pyscreenshot
from pynput.mouse import Listener
x=1
y=1

def on_click(x1, y1, button, pressed):
    global x,y
    x = x1
    y = y1

def on_release(x2,y2, button, pressed):
    global x,y
    im = pyscreenshot.grab(x,y,x2,y2)
    im.save("hello.png")

#Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_click=on_click,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Here the problem is that it don't output anything.Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a code for you. It works fine in my side. Please let me know your opinion after running my code.

```
import pyscreenshot
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button

global x0, y0


def on_click(x1, y1, button, pressed):
    global x0, y0

    if button == Button.left and pressed:
        x0, y0 = x1, y1

    if button == Button.left and not pressed:
        try:
            im = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(x0, y0, x1, y1))
            im.save("hello.png")
            print('Screenshot was taken.')
            return False
        except:
            pass

    return True

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    try:
        listener.join()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Sorry for not upvoting because I don't have enough reputation.In the third line instead of global x0, y0 you should have written  x0=1 and y0=1.It works thank you.Can you please explain what was the problem for my code